# AS3 Custom Event Best Practices Questions (Opinions)

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling

I'm just curious how a lot of you handle custom events.

My custom event/s that I will be creating pertain to creating and displaying views. I want to have two separate events dispatched, one to create the view and then one to display the view. I'd like the create a view using an ID that corresponds to the type of view to create and when displaying the view would like to pass the handler a view object to add to the stage.

I see three ways of doing this:

1. Create a single ViewEvent class with two event types CREATE_VIEW and DISPLAY_VIEW. The problem with a single event class is that I would like if possible to use strongly typed parameters. When using CREATE_VIEW though, I want to pass an ID that corresponds to the view to create and when I dispatch DISPLAY_VIEW I'd like to pass the view object to display. So to get them strongly typed I'd have to two optional parameters, one for viewId of type int and one for view of type DisplayObject and then test for which one exists which I don't like.
2. Same as number 1 except use a single generic parameter and check for it's type to see what the event's payload is which I don't like generic parameters either.
3. Create two separate event classes, a CreateViewEvent and a DisplayViewEvent. This would allow me to use the proper typed parameters, but it seems a little weird since both event actions are so closely related that I feel they should be within the same event class.

So the question is... in general what are everyone's views on handling a situation like this? Is there a better way to handle this?

I've run into this situation before too with other types of events, my view example is just a simple example of what I'm currently running into.

Comment: Who or what dispatches those Events?

Comment: personally I rarely add additional parameters to my custom event classes constructor. Instead I set them as porperties so case 1 is the one I mostly use. I would have 2 properties, when dispatching create_view I only have the id property set when dispatching display_view I only have the view property set so that's var event:CustomEvent = new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CREAT_VIEW); event.id = 'whatever'; dispatchEvent(event);

Comment: How about creating a Custom Class + Subclass for each event type, which will hold the parameter? For example You define a `ViewEventParameter` class, which holds parameters that are useful for both event types. Then you have a sub class `DisplayViewEventParameter` which holds only the information pertaining to that specific event type. In your Event Class, you simply use a parameter of the `ViewEventParameter`class, and through polymorphy you can pass the specific class that is needed for that event. Interfaces would work too.